# Creating a category from inside any 3rd party model

Tags: category, custom-component

Hi I need some help creating a category from inside an upgrade method for a custom component.

This is what I have tried to do, any help will be great!

```
// start up the DB
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
// Select all fields
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('a.category_name','a.desc','a.published'),array('title','description','published')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('jos_oldcomponent_categories', 'a'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('a.id') . ' = '. (int) $id);
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
if ($db->getNumRows())
{
    // get the category
    $item = $db->loadAssoc();
    $item['id'] = 0;
    $item['alias'] = $this->getAlias($item['title']);
    $item['path'] = $item['alias'];
    $item['access'] = 1;
    $item['created_user_id'] = 50;
    $item['created_time'] = '2012-09-18 10:09:09';
    $item['version'] = 1;
    $item['language'] = "*";
    $item['parent_id'] = 1;
    $item['level'] = 1;
    $item['extension'] = 'com_newcomponent';
    // load some joomla helpers
    JLoader::import('joomla.application.component.model');
    // load the model file
    JLoader::import( 'category', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_categories/models' );
    // return instance
    $model = JModelLegacy::getInstance( 'category', 'CategoriesModel' );
    // now save the data
    $model->save($item);
}
```

But this does not work, it seems like the model does not see the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my installer script of DPCalendar I'm using the following code to create a default category:

```
        JTable::addIncludePath(JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/joomla/database/table');
        $category = JTable::getInstance('Category');
        $category->extension = 'com_dpcalendar';
        $category->title = 'Uncategorised';
        $category->alias = 'uncategorised';
        $category->description = '';
        $category->published = 1;
        $category->access = 1;
        $category->params = '{"category_layout":"","image":"","color":"3366CC"}';
        $category->metadata = '{"author":"","robots":""}';
        $category->language = '*';
        $category->setLocation(1, 'last-child');
        $category->store(true);
        $category->rebuildPath($category->id);
```

Hope it helps.